# Compiling GLKit code as Objective-C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++, glkit

I'm trying to compile a project that uses OpenGL, specifically Apple's own GLKit class. When compiling sources ("Compile Sources As" in Build Settings) as file type or Objective-C I get no errors. As I am trying to compile against an external library that relies on Objective-C++ build files, I get linker errors over the GLKXXX classes and methods when I try o compile as Objective-C++

I have tried renaming files to .mm but this does not help the situation

Comment: What are the linker errors you're seeing? Are you actually linking against GLKit.framework?

Comment: Usually "Compile Sources As" is set to "According to File Type". There is no need to change it.